# Using maven commands in the Intellij terminal returns Process terminated

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have maven installed and linked to the project through specifying the home path ([Maven home path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEYkh.png)) in the project settings as Intellij instructs. Whenever running any command with the `mvn` prefix like `mvn -v` it returns `Process Terminated`

[Process Terminated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxqIu.png)

If run without the ide the terminal returns `C:\Users\jacec\OneDrive\Desktop\DMA\maventest>mvn -v 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Could by caused by you antivirus/security tool. Check the Windows Event Log. Also try adding Maven home directory, `bin` subdirectory to the `PATH` environment variable and reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal might be different with intellij setup. You can run the maven task through maven tool window from Intellij tab, like this
[tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html).
[image: example maven toolbar]

Or if you insist to use through the terminal, you might want to check your environment variables in your windows settings. And add variable `MAVEN_HOME` with the value of the maven install directory. Then add value `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` in your system `Path` variable.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know this existed. Which of the tasks would I use if I just want to run my project like normal?

Comment: `mvn install` to build your project. But to run, you should specify the main entry of your application by yourself in Intellij configuration. You can check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html)

Comment: I have made a run/debug configuration for maven but upon running it I get the same error as before `No goals specified`

Comment: You should create the run config as your app main locates. For example, for a spring application you can configure command from maven `mvn spring-boot:run`. or if you have your own main application, just right-click your java main class and select run. BUT, that is as well for another post question. As for this post question, my answer should fix your problem